# jQuery .load() function stops me from calling a script in HTML-file

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, html, ajax

My login.html file:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
    "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" lang="lv">
<head>
<?php require_once 'inc/metahead.php'; ?>
<title>Logg inn</title>
<script type="text/javascript"      src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3.0/jquery.min.js">
</script>
<script type="text/Javascript" src="functions.js">
</script> 

</head>
<body>
    <div id="content">
        <center>
            <form>
                <label for="epost"></label> <input type="text"   name="epost" id="epost"
                    placeholder="Epost/Bruker" /></br> </br> <label
                    for="passord"></label> <input type="password"   name="passord" id="passord"
                    placeholder="Passord" /></br> </br> <input
                    type="button" onclick="login()" value="Logg inn">
            </form>
            <br /> <a href="forgot_pass.php">Glemt passord?</a>
        </center>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

This piece of code is from my header.php file:

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
function loginNow(){
    $(document).ready(function() {
         $("#content").load("login.html");
    });
}
</script>
```

If i go directly in login.html - It calls the function without problems. BUT, if I go through my index-file and click "Logg inn", so the script above run, the script in login.html never gets called.

I have tried to alert something out instead of calling my script - That works. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

what i think is you have two jquery files with different version loaded there which is creating the conflict

```
 <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3.0/jquery.min.js">
```

in login.html

and other is

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
```

in header.php

so either you use [noConflict()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.noConflict/).. or remove one of them

Comment: That was it. I would've never catched that X)

Answer (score 1):

The function name is different here

```
 onclick="login()" // you are calling login()

 function loginNow(){ // but declaring loginNow()
```

Comment: i think this is not right... i don't thik OP wants to call that function there.. since if you look inside the function you will notice it is  loading login.html.. which is the same page... :)

Answer (score 0):

Your HTML code:
...

```
<input type="password"   name="passord" id="passord"
                    placeholder="Passord" /></br> </br> <input
                    type="button" **onclick="login()"** value="Logg inn">
```

...

Your Javascript Code:

```
function **loginNow()**{
    $(document).ready(function() {
         $("#content").load("login.html");
    });
}
```

Check the enclosed parts - Different function names ;)

Comment: i think this is not right... i don't thik OP wants to call that function there.. since if you look inside the function you will it will load login.html.. which is the same page... :)

Comment: Thank you! I guess I was a little unclear: The loginNow script loads the login.hmtl file. My html file will THEN load my login-script. loginNow and login are two different scripts

Comment: Indeed, you got me confused on this part. On the other hand, check out bipen's answer.

Answer (score 0):

Don't use `onlick=""`. Since you are using jQuery, hook an event to your input element:

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
     $('input[type=button]').click(loginNow);
 });
```

Eventually give the button an `id` or a `name` and use this as the selector in jQuery.